# Visual Studio 2019 creating .NetStandard 2.0.3 libraries instead of 2.1 inside a .Net Core 3.1 solution

Tags: visual-studio-2019, .net-core-3.1

i've recently (yesterday) updated visual studio 2019. I have access to .net core 3.1 sdk and can create .net core 3.1 projects. However, when i try to create a .net standard library, it defaults to 2.0.3 instead of 2.1.

As far as i understand, .net standard 2.1 should come with .net core 3.1.

Am i misunderstanding something here?

Comment: I guess for better compatibility as NS2.1 is not usable from classic .NET 4 framework apps. Open [properties of lib and change target to NS2.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/core/tutorials/media/library-with-visual-studio/library-project-properties.png)

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks for the answer. Indeed i can change that trough the properties, however this solution will have quite a bit of projects (20+ ish). Currently there are already around 10 done, do i really have to change all of them manually each time?

Comment: you can also open csproj in notepad and change it here faster

Comment: @magicandre1981 That's still manual change. I wanted Visual Studio to create a new NS 2.1 project by itself.

Comment: I've posted the steps to create a NS2.1 template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a blank solution and add a new `Class Library (.NET Standard)`. In properties change the target framework to `.NET Standard 2.1`

[image]

Save the changes and click on `Project`->`Export template`:

[image]

and create an [`Project template` based](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-project-templates?view=vs-2019#use-the-export-template-wizard) on the class lib project.

[image]

give it a name and description and finish.

[image]

and when you create a new project, select your generated template and now it is always set to `.NET Standard 2.1` instead of `.NET Standard 2.0`.

Comment: Well, not really what i had in mind but it covers my problem, so thanks.