# Visual Studio 2019 will only Targets 2.0 Framework for Class Libraries

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I'm using VS 2019 and having lots of issues with this IDE.  I'll explain some of the bugs I'm experiencing.

I have created a Class library in Visual Studio 2019, and for some reason it is using the 2.0 framework.  It is possible to set the target framework with Winform or Web application project types, but I don't know how to do it for Class library project (even when it's added to a blank solution and WinForm or Web projects) and I don't believe it is possible with my Visual Studio.

Two issues which I am experiencing that may help.

1. IIF statements are not recognized.
   Error   BC30451 'iif' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
2. IsNothing is not recognized
   Error   BC30451 'IsNothing' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio 2019 creating .NetStandard 2.0.3 libraries instead of 2.1 inside a .Net Core 3.1 solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59550768/visual-studio-2019-creating-netstandard-2-0-3-libraries-instead-of-2-1-inside-a)